# Multiple buffer objects vs a single large manually managed one?

Tags: opengl

I have a large number of chunks of data (hundreds to thousands) with the same size (several kb), which are loaded and unloaded frequently in an unpredictable manner (depending on the movements of the camera).

I am wondering if it is best, performance and/or resource wise, to allocate a big buffer, and dynamically reserve parts of it for each loaded chunks, rather than allocate a buffer object for each chunk?
In other words, is it bad to have a lot of separate buffer objects, when you can combine them into one (with some work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is not the amount of VBOs, but how large the content is (it shouldn't be too small) and reallocating a VBO. In your particular case, where you're frequently updating data having a small number of memory pool VBOs is usually better, then putting each chunk of data into its own VBO.

> loaded and unloaded frequently in an unpredictable manner (depending on the movements of the camera)

You shouldn't do that. By which I mean use the view to decide what's loaded and whats not. Just load everything you possibly might need at the moment in the VBO and just reference it when actually required. But don't loose yourself in micromanaging each and every piece of data at every small time step. When you know, that something definitely won't show up ever again, then unload it. And if something might show up some time later, then load it early.

You don't have to draw everything contained in a VBO.

Comment: In my particular case I am generating those chunks procedurally in real time, so it's hard to load them in advance. However keeping them in memory until they are overwritten sounds like a good idea.